# Advanced webscraping

Tags: web-scraping

For starters, my question is in fact from the series "Can it be done?".

Let's take a look at the [webpage](http://cngcoins.com/Coin.aspx?CoinID=323425). Here we have an internet auction and  we see these lines in the middle of the page:

[image]

Here we see that the highest bid is **60$**, and the bidder's name is **seanpatrick**. Lower on the screen we see an interface to place bids on the current coin.

[image]

CNG has already introduced a bidding system here. First of all, you decide how much you can pay for the coin, and enter the figure into the **your Maximum bid ($)** field. Then you enter **Bidder Handle** (simply, your login) and your password to the corresponding fields, press **Submit Bid**. As we can see, the figure in the **Your Maximum bid ($)** is automatically filled with **65$**. It means that the lowest bid now is **65$**, but if you are ready to pay more, say a **100$**, you type in **100$** and the website will automatically bid for you (of course, until your maximum bid is reached).
The information I want to gain is what maximum bid is entered by **seanpatrick**? So say, he enters **95$** in the **Maximum bid** field, and I decide to enter **100$** there, then website will automatically increment the bids by **bid increment** (for the current coin it is **5$**), and when the bid reaches **100$** (one step over his maximum), and I'm becoming the highest bidder.

I want to figure out where this automatic bidding process happens, and can the maximum bid be intercepted from the outside? I tackled the website with Chrome Developer Tools, looked over uploaded packages, but didn't find anything related to problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you need to check it regulary (or once prior to bid closing date).
See, now the last bid has changed and the bidder name too:
[image]

So, knowing the bid closing time you might check the last bid at the moment prior to bid closure. Then you:

1. Log in
2. SUBMIT A FORM WITH YOUR BID

It can be done.

### Update

On the screenshot you may see the *Current bid*: **Currently: $65**.
So you might get that figure at first page request and at the second request you place your bid and submit form.

Comment: You didn't understand my question

Comment: The fact that my maximum bid field is now 70 doesn't mean that I'll get the highest bid. This guy no_pasaran could have entered, say, 100$, and then my bid will momentarily get overridden by his. And I want to know what sum I have to enter to really get the highest bid (but I want to find it out experimentally by just typing it in, i want to find a smart way=))